# linux shell script: how can I create a service that will run in background?

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have a simple question, i searched and I couldn't find a solution.

I have a simple shell script that run a small php code every 2 seconds, I wrote it and save as a file:

```
$ cat every-2-seconds.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
php /home/account/domains/domain.co.il/public_html/my-php-script.php
 sleep 2
done
```

Now, i need that this script will always run on background, but I also need that it will run on startup, **Just like a service**, it should always run in background, and I never want to start it manually (of course, if something happen and it will stop, i should be able to start it manually)
I heard about nohup, but its not a service right? and I can start it on startup.. :(

Can you help me on this??

Comment: try to use [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: thanks!, I thought about that, but the script is running every 2 seconds, in CronJob, 1 minute is the minimum :(

Comment: check if your crontab accepts the `@reboot` special string. or add it to `/etc/init.d`

Comment: Maybe have a look at Upstart and inittab - http://serverfault.com/questions/449204/ubuntu-how-to-kill-a-respawn-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your script run with this line of code (assuming you are in the directory with your script)

```
nohup every-2-seconds.sh &
```

The `&` will run this as a background task and `nohup` will keep the process running even after you've disconnected from your session.

To handle starting it on [reboot](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/) you need to add this command to your crontab

```
crontab -e
@reboot /path/to/every-2-seconds.sh > /dev/null
```

In the crontab you need to specify the full path. You can change `/dev/null` to the file you want output to go to (assuming you want the output)

Comment: I'm testing it, Thank you!!